# How to normalize Needleman Wunsch similarity score

Tags: bigdata, string-matching, similarity, tf-idf, normalize

I've been learning about String Matching algorithms. However, I'm quite confused about the algorithm Needleman-Wunsch. It states that we can find the **similarity score** based on the **defined scoring system**, but I don't see anywhere saying normalizing the score. Do we have that concept here? If yes, how to normalize the score so that it can range from 0 to 1?

Furthermore, I follow an example demonstrated on [Big Data: hybrid similarity measure: the Soft TF/IDF Measure to deal with misspelt words](https://sistemanalize.wordpress.com/2017/12/19/big-data-hybrid-similarity-measure-the-soft-tf-idf-measure/). I don't understand how the (normalized?) similarity score between two string "apple" and "ibm" in the table below is calculated. This leads to the question above!
[Needleman-Wusnch and Jaro-Winkler similarity scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUTU0.png)

I tried to find the formula to normalize the score but seeing nothing promising.